# Bash string starting with ">"

Tags: bash

I need to check if a word is starting with ">" character or not

for example A=">abcd" should return true, B="assdf" should not.

I Tried the following snippets but it does not work

```
if [ "$A" == "\>*" ]; then
    echo "True"
fi
```

The following does not work also

```
A=">dfssdfsd"
    if [[ "$A" =~ "\>*" ]]; then
    echo "aaa"
fi
```

Thank you

Comment: Use double brackets and =~ i.e `if [[ "$A" =~ ^\> ]]`

Comment: This does work. Thank you

Comment: Why is this duplicate, > is a special character, I already looked over that answer it does not answer to my question.

Comment: All of the answers in the duplicate work for your problem, therefore it is a duplicate. A single character difference is not a new question. If your question is how to escape special characters then ask that.

Comment: As 123 mentioned not to double-quote the RegEx, you also do not need to use double-quotes on `$A` when using double square brackets, e.g., `A="> dfssdfsd"; [[ $A =~ ^\>* ]] && echo "Yes"` will answer `Yes` as the space in `"> dfssdfsd"` will not split inside of double square brackets.  Note that I know `$A` in the example is `>dfssdfsd` without a space and my example is to show that there is no splitting when inside double square brackets and therefore why `$A` does not need to be quoted either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
expr "$A" : '>'
```

> ```
> $ if [ 0 -ne $(expr 'test' : '>') ]; then echo "True"; else echo "False"; fi
> False
> $ if [ 0 -ne $(expr '>test' : '>') ]; then echo "True"; else echo "False"; fi
> True
> ```